Authorize.net Transaction Details API: XML Errors
I am using Authorize CNP API with PHP. API is working fine with other cards but throwing error E00003 for few cards.
Following is the XML response. Not sure where it is taking phoneNumber as I am not sending it anymore.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ErrorResponse
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd">
    <messages>
        <resultCode>Error</resultCode>
        <message>
            <code>E00003</code>
            <text>The \'AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd:phoneNumber\' element is invalid - The value XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX is invalid according to its datatype \'String\' - The actual length is greater than the MaxLength value.</text>
        </message>
    </messages>
</ErrorResponse>


Try logging the XML before it's sent to see what it contains

Aah, my client saved string with phone number into database.
